# How to parse this accounting number format?

Tags: sqlite, format, accounting

KMyMoney (open source personal finance manager) exports to an SQLite database. Dollar amount data is stored in table `kmmSplits` as several text fields in a strange format based on “value” and “valueFormatted” (see screen shot below). The “value” field is apparently written as a division equation (in a text format) which yields the “valueFormatted” field (again in text format). The “valueFormatted is the correct number amount but the problem is parenthesis are used to indicate a negative number instead of a minus in front of the value.

I don’t know how to parse this into a float value for running calculated queries. The positive values (without parenthesis) are no problem to convert. I’ve tried CAST to FLOAT but this does not do the division math, nor convert parenthesis to negative values. How to parse a text value containing parenthesis in the “valueFormatted field (accounting money format) into a common number format? Alternatively, how to convert a division equation in the “value” field  to an actual calculation?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` expression to check if `valueFormatted` is a numeric value inside parentheses and if it is multiply `-1` with the substring starting from the 2nd char (the closing parenthesis will be discarded by SQLite during this implicit type casting):

```
SELECT *,
       CASE
         WHEN valueFormatted LIKE '(%)' THEN (-1) * SUBSTR(valueFormatted, 2)
         ELSE valueFormatted
       END AS value
FROM kmmSQLite;
```

Or, replace `'('` with ''-'' and add `0` to covert the result to a number:

```
SELECT *,
       REPLACE(valueFormatted, '(', '-') + 0 AS value
FROM kmmSQLite;
```

Comment: Interestingly,

If I use:

SELECT
 CASE
         WHEN kmmSplits.valueFormatted LIKE '(%)' THEN (-1) * SUBSTR(valueFormatted, 2)
         ELSE kmmSplits.valueFormatted
 END AS theCost,

 sum(kmmSplits.valueFormatted) as 'TOTAL'

I get the wrong sum total, BUT if I save this as a VIEW, then run it as a subquery:

SELECT
  TAG,
  sum(theCost)
FROM
  (SELECT * FROM myView)

I get the correct sum total

Comment: @user1526973 `theCost` is the alias of a calculated column and you can't use it in the same SELECT statement's column list.

Answer (score 0):

I use KmMyMoney and access the same table's "fraction" field "kmmSplits"."shares" (which accurately store values without rounding them) using the following expression (explained below)

ROUND(((CAST(substr ("kmmSplits"."shares", 1, (instr ("kmmSplits"."shares", '/' ) - 1 ) ) AS REAL ) ) / (CAST( substr( "kmmSplits"."shares", ( instr( "kmmSplits"."shares", '/' ) + 1 ), LENGTH( "kmmSplits"."shares" )) AS REAL ))),2) "Qty"

N.B This expression has the optional alias "Qty" tacked on otherwise sqlite will use the formula as the field name.

### EXPLANATION:

Converting a fraction stored as TEXT, requires parsing the text based upon the (4) positions of the first and last characters for both Numerator and Denominator

1. Numerator's start position is 1

The last character of the numerator and the first character of the denominator lie either side of the fraction's "/" sign which can be found using the "instr" expression:

```
    instr ("kmmSplits"."shares", '/' )
```

Therefore:

2. The numerator's last character is at position:

   ```
    (instr ("kmmSplits"."shares", '/' ) - 1)
   ```
3. The denominator's first character is at position:

   ```
    (instr ("kmmSplits"."shares", '/' ) + 1)
   ```
4. Denominator's end position = the length of the fraction as determined by

   ```
    LENGTH( "kmmSplits"."shares" )
   ```

Use these positions in a "substring" expressions:

### PARSE the NUMERATOR:

```
    (substr ("kmmSplits"."shares", 1, (instr ("kmmSplits"."shares", '/' ) - 1 )
```

Then CAST it as a REAL number -  (so sqlite can subsequently divide it by the denominator)

```
    CAST(substr ("kmmSplits"."shares", 1, (instr ("kmmSplits"."shares", '/' ) - 1 ) ) AS REAL )
```

### PARSE the DENOMINATOR:

```
    substr( "kmmSplits"."shares", ( instr( "kmmSplits"."shares", '/' ) + 1 ), LENGTH( "kmmSplits"."shares" )
```

Then CAST it as a REAL number

```
    CAST( substr( "kmmSplits"."shares", ( instr( "kmmSplits"."shares", '/' ) + 1 ), LENGTH( "kmmSplits"."shares" )) AS REAL )
```

### DIVIDE the NUMERATOR by the DENOMINATOR (as REAL numbers):

```
    ((CAST(substr ("kmmSplits"."shares", 1, (instr ("kmmSplits"."shares", '/' ) - 1 ) ) AS REAL ) ) / (CAST( substr( "kmmSplits"."shares", ( instr( "kmmSplits"."shares", '/' ) + 1 ), LENGTH( "kmmSplits"."shares" )) AS REAL ))) "Qty"
```

### ROUNDING DECIMAL PLACES:

```
    ROUND(((CAST(substr ("kmmSplits"."shares", 1, (instr ("kmmSplits"."shares", '/' ) - 1 ) ) AS REAL ) ) / (CAST( substr( "kmmSplits"."shares", ( instr( "kmmSplits"."shares", '/' ) + 1 ), LENGTH( "kmmSplits"."shares" )) AS REAL ))),2) "Qty"
```

N.B The last 2 expressions have the optional alias "Qty" tacked on the end otherwise sqlite will use the formula as the field name